# How to prevent stdin stream from reading data from associated file descriptor on program start?

Tags: c, linux, filestream, file-descriptor

I'm using select() call to detect input presence in the main cycle of my program. This makes me use raw file descriptor (0) instead of stdin.

While working in this mode I've noticed that my software occasionally loses a chunk of input at the beginning. I suspect that stdin consumes some of it on the program start. Is there a way to prevent this behavior of stdin or otherwise get the whole input data?

The effect described can be reproduced only with some data on standard input at the very moment of program start. My executable should be used as xinetd service in a way that it always has some input on the start.

Standard input is read in the following way:

```
Error processInput() {
  struct timeval ktimeout;
  int fd=fileno(stdin);
  int maxFd=fd+1;
  FD_ZERO(&fdset);
  FD_SET(fd, &fdset);
  ktimeout.tv_sec = 0;
  ktimeout.tv_usec = 1;
  int selectRv=-1;
  while ((selectRv=select(maxFd, &fdset, NULL, NULL, &ktimeout)) > 0) {
    int left=MAX_BUFFER_SIZE-position-1;
    assert(left>0);
    int bytesCount=read(fd, buffer+position, left);
    //Input processing goes here
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some relevant code?

Comment: Pseudocode has been added to illustrate a process of input reading.

Comment: Why even reference `stdin` at all? Why not just use `int fd = 0`, or perhaps `int fd = STDIN_FILENO`?

Comment: Does that matter in my case? I may use STDIN_FILENO there, but that won't help to abandon the whole  stdio.h, as I use standard error stream elsewhere.

Comment: In C++ that would matter (I'm using pure C). I'll try to remove all references to stdin and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix cooked and raw meat together. Try replacing the read() call with the equivalent fread() call.

It is very likely that `fileno(stdin)` is initializing the stdin object, causing it to read and buffer some input. Or perhaps you are already calling something that causes it to initialize (scanf(), getchar(), etc...).

Comment: Perhaps he should go the other direction, and avoid fileno(stdin).  Instead, use the well known fd number of zero for stdin.

Comment: Juliano, you  mean there is an asynchronous interface for streams in C? Can you please reference a manual about it?

Comment: @Basilevs: It is the same interface, actually. Just use fread() only when you know for sure that there is something to read (after a successful return from select()) and you will be doing asynchronous communication. You can also set O_NONBLOCK in the file descriptor using fctrl(), to guarantee that fread() will return EAGAIN if there is nothing to be read from that descriptor.

Comment: Select does not work with fread (fread blocks after succesful select). I've used the second suggested approach.